# Jquery select top level descendants with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

assume i have a DOM like:

```
<body>
<div class="a" data="a"><!-- 1 -->
    <div>
        <div class="a" data="b"><!-- 2 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a" data="c"><!-- 3 -->
        <div class="a" data="d"><!-- 4 -->
            <div class="a" data="e"><!-- 5 -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="a" data="f"><!-- 6 -->
            <div class="a" data="g"><!-- 7 -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="a" data="h"><!-- 8 -->

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

how can i select top level elements of matched elements that have the class `a`?

for example `$('body').selector...` should select 1 and 8.
`$('[data="a"]').selector...` should select 2 and 3.
`$('[data="c"]').selector...` should select 4 and 6.
please note that html structure is just an example, it could has any other structure.

Comment: This seems similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712377/match-only-the-first-descendent-in-pure-css), asked just a couple minutes apart, except that one is looking for pure CSS.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think this can be done with a pure CSS selector, or at least not a non-horrible CSS selector :-)  There's no way I know of to specify an ancestor relationship that excludes intermediate sub-selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it by add my own selector:

```
$.fn.topLevel = function(sel) {
    var master = $(this);
  return master.find(sel).filter(function() {
    return $(this).parentsUntil(master,sel).length == 0;
  });
};
```

but i still think that there is more *tricky* solution.

Answer (score 0):

A good (though slightly tricky) way to do things like this is to think about it backwards. To find (in your example) 1 and 8, you could do:

```
var oneAndEight = $('.a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('.a').length === 0;
});
```

That's all the ".a" elements with no other ".a" elements closer to the DOM root. To get 2 and 3, you'd look for those with just one ".a" between the element and the root.

To generalize, here's a simple plugin:

```
$.atDepth = function(sel, depth) {
  return $(sel).filter(function() {
    return $(this).parents(sel).length == depth;
  });
});
```

To get 1 and 8:

```
var oneAndEight = $.atDepth(".a", 0);
```

For 5 and 7:

```
var fiveAndSeven = $.atDepth(".a", 3);
```

I don't think this can be done with a simple selector, because CSS selector syntax doesn't have a "anything not including x" mechanism.

*edit* — [here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/opofoh/1);

Comment: $(this).closest('.a') will select the element itself if it has class a so nothing will be returned

Comment: @AkramBerkawy fixed.  I must be sleepy :-)

Comment: it works for 1 and 8 but not others, i have edited the question please read it again :-)

Comment: @AkramBerkawy [here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/opofoh/1) - I had a minor error that's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
$(".a:not(.a .a)")
```

Comment: how this will select 4 and 6 starting from `$('[data="c"]')` ?