# Match only the first descendent in pure css?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there an elegant way in pure css to match *only* the first descendent -- similar to jquery first()?

in jQuery:

```
$(".outer .title").first();
```

Mark-up will vary, so using the direct descendent > selector is unreliable.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="inner">
     <div class="title" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this answer is based on a structure which has now been edited in the question:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="thing">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="thing" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With nesting like that, the best option is to *revert* the styles if the object is within itself;

```
.outer .thing { /* styles */ }
.thing .thing { /* revert styles */ }
```

With a structure like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="thing" />
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="thing" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You have fewer options;

```
/* assume thing will always be a direct child of outer */
.outer > .thing {}

/* assume thing will always be the VERY FIRST child of outer */
.outer > thing:first-child {}

/* assume thing will always be inside the VERY FIRST child of outer */
.outer > .thing:first-child, .outer > *:first-child .thing {}

/* assume the thing you don't want will always be inside inner */
.outer .thing {}
.inner .thing { /* revert styles */ }
```

Both structures are silly though. This looks like headings/sub-headings, in which case you can do this:

```
<header>
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
</header>
```

or

```
<hgroup>
    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>
</hgroup>
```

or to stay away from standard tags:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="title" />
    <div class="subtitle" />
</div>
```

or using multiple classes

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="title maintitle" />
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="title subtitle" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: best answer IMO. other answers don't consider the fact that descendant is not necessarily a _direct_ child (selected by >) of an element. And `:first-child` matches an element that is **first** child of said element. The markup can change to contain other element as first child of said element

Comment: Agree the structure is silly -- I have modified it to something more sensible.

Comment: @user1031947 With your updated structure, this is *much* more difficult. In fact, to my knowledge, it would be impossible unless we can assume that `title` will always be the *very first* element within `outer`, or other `title`s will always be within specific other objects, or the main `title` will always be a direct descendent. Your structure needs to be more logical. Does it actually make sense that these are both the same element type? Maybe you should restyle an element which is within `inner` rather than omit it from the first styling.

Answer (score 2):

Look up CSS selectors - [W3Schools CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

This might be what you're looking for though:
`.outer .thing:first-child {}`

You could also try `nth-child()`

Comment: The inner `.thing` is also a first-child of `.stuff`, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: I only want to select the first .title (.outer>.title) -- first-child will select all first-children